# prevent duplicate creation of categories in PrestaShop

Tags: prestashop, categories

there is a way to prevent duplicate creation of categories in prestashop?

That's because I want use categories like artist name:

category: The Beatles

product1: Please Please Me 
product2: With the Beatles
product3: A Hard Day's Night 
etc

I want prevent that admin could insert another category like this "the beatles" (for not disperse the products across multiple categories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding new file called **AdminCategoriesController.php** in **/prestashop/override/controllers/admin/**

```
<?php 
class AdminCategoriesController extends AdminCategoriesControllerCore{

public function processAdd()
{

    $id_category = (int)Tools::getValue('id_category');
    $id_parent = (int)Tools::getValue('id_parent');

    // if true, we are in a root category creation
    if (!$id_parent)
    {
                $_POST['is_root_category'] = $_POST['level_depth'] = 1;
                $_POST['id_parent'] = $id_parent = (int)Configuration::get('PS_ROOT_CATEGORY');
    }

    if ($id_category)
    {
        if ($id_category != $id_parent)
        {
            if (!Category::checkBeforeMove($id_category, $id_parent))
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The category cannot be moved here.');
        }
        else
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The category cannot be a parent of itself.');
    }


            $categoryName = (!empty($_POST['name_1'])) ? $_POST['name_1'] : $_POST['name_2'];
            $duplicated = Category::searchByName(0, $categoryName, true);

            if($duplicated){
                Tools::redirectAdmin(self::$currentIndex.'&id_category='.(int)Configuration::get('PS_ROOT_CATEGORY').'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminCategories').'&conf=4');
                return ;
            }
    $object = parent::processAdd();

    //if we create a you root category you have to associate to a shop before to add sub categories in. So we redirect to AdminCategories listing
    if ($object && Tools::getValue('is_root_category'))
        Tools::redirectAdmin(self::$currentIndex.'&id_category='.(int)Configuration::get('PS_ROOT_CATEGORY').'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminCategories').'&conf=3');
    return $object;
}
}
```

You can change the user message for duplicate entry here by change "conf" parameter

```
Tools::redirectAdmin(self::$currentIndex.'&id_category='.(int)Configuration::get('PS_ROOT_CATEGORY').'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminCategories').'&conf=1234');
```

**do not forget to delete class_index.php inside /prestashop/cache**

Answer (score 0):

Override the processAdd() function on AdminCategoriesController to add your name control. 
Use searchByName() function in Category Class to do that.